# Need working gnome-shell configuration for docking laptop with an external monitor

Tags: 16.04, gnome, multiple-monitors, suspend

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a Thinkpad T440s (Intel graphics) using an Ultra Dock with an attached monitor, keyboard and mouse.  Given the hubbub about Ubuntu deprecating Unity, I thought I'd try Gnome shell (which turned out as a pleasant surprise: maybe I'll just stick with it.)

It's all mostly good, but I find that when I dock the suspended laptop that was previously undocked and resume, the login screen is on the laptop, as if it doesn't seem to recognize that that the lid is closed.
If open the laptop and shut it again, this sometimes turns off the laptop screen and then I can log in as usual.

This seemed to "just work" under Unity.  This makes me think that there is some gnome-shell configuration change that will fix this.

Does anybody have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Different laptop, but same problem. This is clunky, but having logged in on my laptop, I set the two displays to mirror each other and then sudo cp ~/.config/monitors.xml /var/lib/gdm3/.config/